# Incomplete metric on $\mathbb{N}$, set of Natural Number

Tags: metric-spaces

$\mathbb{N}$  is complete with respect to usual metric.

But if I define $d(x, y) =|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}|$ then $\mathbb{N}$ is incomplete. How to show this?  It is quite interesting.

I thought about a cauchy sequence which is not convergent but unable to do that.

Comment: Consider the sequence $1,2,3,\ldots$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Every strictly increasing sequence is Cauchy with this metric.

---

*<strike>[Additional Comment: In fact, a sequence $(a_n)$ is Cauchy in this space if and only if $a_n\to\infty$.]</strike>*

*[Additional Additional Comment: My previous comment was wrong (thanks, @Mars Plastic). Striking it out. ]*

Comment: Your additional comment isn't quite true, as the constant sequences obviously converge.

Comment: @MarsPlastic : You are correct, of course. Editing. +1 for you.

Comment: On the other hand $(a_n)$ is Cauchy and divergent if and only if $a_n \to \infty$.